# How to query the participant orgs of a hyperledger fabric with node?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I would like to give the opportunity to one org to query the names of the participant organizations on the fabric samples. I searched on the node sdk documentation and i found the function getOrganizations(); which return an Array of OrganizationIdentifier Objects representing the channel's participating organizations.

Here is a sample code

```
async function initGatewayForOrg1() {
    console.log(`${GREEN}--> Fabric client user & Gateway init: Using Org1 identity to Org1 Peer${RESET}`);

    const ccpOrg1 = buildCCPOrg1();

    const caOrg1Client = buildCAClient(FabricCAServices, ccpOrg1, 'ca.org1.example.com');


    const walletPathOrg1 = path.join(__dirname, 'wallet', 'org1');
    const walletOrg1 = await buildWallet(Wallets, walletPathOrg1);

    await enrollAdmin(caOrg1Client, walletOrg1, org1);
    await registerAndEnrollUser(caOrg1Client, walletOrg1, org1, Org1UserId, 'org1.department1');

    try {
        const gatewayOrg1 = new Gateway();
        await gatewayOrg1.connect(ccpOrg1,
            { wallet: walletOrg1, identity: Org1UserId, discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true } });

        return gatewayOrg1;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error in connecting to gateway for Org1: ${error}`);
        process.exit(1);
    }
}

async function main() {
    console.log(`${GREEN} **** START ****${RESET}`);
    try {
        const gatewayOrg1 = await initGatewayForOrg1();
        const networkOrg1 = await gatewayOrg1.getNetwork(channelName);
        const channelOrgs = networkOrg1.getOrganizations();
        } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error in setup: ${error}`);
        if (error.stack) {
            console.error(error.stack);
        }
        process.exit(1);
    }
    console.log(` **** END ****`);
}
main();
```

But the output is:

**Error in setup: TypeError: networkOrg1.getOrganizations is not a function
TypeError: networkOrg1.getOrganizations is not a function**

Does anybody what is the error? Or any other solution?

Comment: Hi HectorCode! Which version of Hyperledger Fabric are you using? As david_k mentioned in his response, that methos it is nos available for the version 2.2 of the SDK

Comment: Hello @Urko. Yes i didn't know that and i was trying for the version 2.2

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which version of the node-sdk you are using so

The error is saying that there is no `getOrganizations` method on networkOrg1 which is correct, that method does not exist on the network object in either node-sdk 1.4 or node-sdk 2.2

That method only exists on the channel object in node-sdk 1.4 (ie not in node-sdk 2.2). In node-sdk 1.4 you can get the channel object from the network object using the `getChannel` method.